# Explanation of this format string used in PHP sprintf

Tags: php, printf

I have been using `echo "$".sprintf("%01\$.2f",$numvar);` for my USD formatting, but I only copied and pasted that. I looked over the documentation at php.net but it's still not clear to me.

Please help me understand what each part of `"%01\$.2f"` does in that function.

Comment: Good examples at http://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/sprintf-function/

Comment: The good examples are actually in the PHP Manual itself: http://php.net/sprintf - whenever you have a problem / question with a specific function in PHP visit the manual page. As you already looked there, what part specifically did you not understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `%` is the start of the *conversion specification*
- `01\$` signifies that the value will be placed in the first item of the result

  <sup>More usually, the same would be written as `1$`</sup>
- `.2` is the *precision specifier*, which dictates how many decimal digits should be displayed
- `f` means that the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware)

For full details of the above, and what is available, see the description of the `format` parameter of [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: Is there a real purpose for the \, though?  With it or without it, it seems to produce the same result.

Comment: @kevin628 in this case no, since `$.` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: It can be simplified to '%1$.2f', that says: take the first argument and format it as a float, two digits after point.

Comment: @Alex yes, the `01\$` is interpreted in the same way as `1$` since the `0` is gobbled up while looking for the argument number and the \, as noted above, is redundant (as is `1$` really).

Comment: Thank you, salathe and @Alex. The answer and that comment combined helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the `sprint` function is the "format". The possible formats include:

> Possible format values:
>
> 1. %% - Returns a percent sign
> 2. %b - Binary number
> 3. %c - The character according to the ASCII value
> 4. %d - Signed decimal number
> 5. %e - Scientific notation (e.g. 1.2e+2)
> 6. %u - Unsigned decimal number
> 7. %f - Floating-point number (local settings aware)
> 8. %F - Floating-point number (not local settings aware)
> 9. %o - Octal number
> 10. %s - String
> 11. %x - Hexadecimal number (lowercase letters)
> 12. %X - Hexadecimal number (uppercase letters)
>
> Additional format values. These are placed between the % and the
>   letter (example %.2f):
>
> 1. "+"  (Forces both + and - in front of numbers. By default, only negative numbers are marked)
> 2. ' (Specifies what to use as padding. Default is space. Must be used together with the width specifier. Example: %'x20s (this uses "x" as
>      padding)
> 3. "-" (Left-justifies the variable value)
> 4. [0-9] (Specifies the minimum width held of to the variable value)
> 5. .[0-9] (Specifies the number of decimal digits or maximum string length)